# URLDownloadToFile() not working with self-signed certificate

Tags: c++, ssl, https, self-signed

I'm using a self-signed certificate for HTTPS communication. The code below works with HTTP, but not with HTTPS. Running GetLastError() afterwards returns 0. I scoured online, but couldn't find anything that would explain why URLDownloadToFile() won't work with self-signed certificates. Any advice?

```
wstring Url = L"https://192.168.1.100/uploads/test.txt";
wstring Path = L"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.txt";

URLDownloadToFile(NULL, Url.c_str(), Path.c_str(), 0, NULL);
```

Comment: `URLDownloadToFile()` does not use `GetLastError()`, it returns the error code as an `HRESULT`. What is that value? `URLDownloadToFile()` uses WinInet, which is the same library used by Internet Explorer. The certificate in question should be trusted by IE first, did you install the certificate chain beforehand?

Comment: Otherwise, try implementing an `IBindStatusCallback` object to pass to `URLDownloadToFile()`, and have that object also implement `IHttpSecurity` and `IWindowForBindingUI`. `URLDownloadToFile()` will query the `IBindStatusCallback` for `IHttpSecurity`, which has an `OnSecurityProblem` callback.  When displaying a dialog from `IHttpSecurity`, `URLDownloadToFile()` will query for `IWindowForBindingUI`, which has a `GetWindow()` callback to get the owner HWND to use for the dialog. This should allow you to see a popup warning about the certificate (and maybe also accept/reject it?).

Comment: I will try that, and post back with details. Thanks!

Comment: HRESULT Output: HRESULT -2146697191 (0x800C0019) "The Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate is invalid." so it's definitely related to the certificate. Unfortunately, installing the certificate chain is not an option.

Comment: 0x800C0019 is `INET_E_INVALID_CERTIFICATE` (see error codes in `urlmon.h`). Try using WinInet/WinHTTP directly so you can [send your own HTTPS request](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168151), then you can use [`InternetSetOption()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114.aspx) to disable certificate errors. Or use a 3rd party HTTPS library, such as [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) with its [`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) option disabled.

Comment: The link from @RemyLebeau 's comment is not valid anymore. [Here](https://gist.github.com/lxfly2000/e1392e2fb92d60b1640570ae9af10f3d) is some sample code on GitHub referring to the same article.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helps to add the root certificate to the trusted certificate list. It wasn't included there.